# Efficient dot product dense to sparse

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to compute efficiently the dot product of two low rank matrices A and B for specific indexes only. Typically, A and B have shape (100, 10000) and I would like to get only the 1% of the entries of A.T @ B.

I've already tried using the library Numba but it seems to be much slower than computing the dense dot product np.dot(A.T, B).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a subset of the resulting array of a dot product, just take the subset before using dot. Ie., if you want the 'upper-left' 10x10 matrix of the output, just do

```
np.dot(A.T[:10,:], B[:, :10])
```

If you want some particular indices, you can use more fancy indexing. For example, if you want indices 3, 5, and 29, you can do something like this:

```
indices = np.array([3, 5, 29]).reshape(-1, 1)
inner_all = np.arange(A.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)
result = np.dot(A.T[indices, inner_all.T], B[inner_all, indices.T])
```

If you, for the first row only, want columns 1, 3, and 5:

```
rows = np.array([1]).reshape(-1, 1)
columns = rows = np.array([1, 3, 5]).reshape(-1, 1)
inner_all = np.arange(A.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)
result = np.dot(A.T[rows, inner_all.T], B[inner_all, columns.T])
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. However in my case, the output is not an array. For instance on the row 0, I may want to compute 3 coefficients while on the row 1, I  may need 20 coefficients.

Comment: @AdrienVacher The result of a dot product is an array. If you just want a subset of that array, say 3 coefficients in the first row, then please see my updated answer.

Comment: I want to compute for each row of A a different number of dot products with the columns of B. Actually, I want to compute efficiently A.T@B [mask] where mask is a 2d mask of shape (A.shape[1], B.shape[1]) and has many zeros (sparse mask). Many "unused" computations are involved and I looking for an efficient way to by pass that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `einsum`:

```
import numpy as np

def direct():
    return (A.T@B)[iy, ix]

def einsum():
    return np.einsum('ij,ij->j',A[:,iy],B[:,ix])

def make(M,N,p):
    global A,B,iy,ix
    A,B = (np.random.randint(0,10,(M,N)) for _ in "AB")
    iy,ix = np.random.randint(0,N,(2,int(N*N*p)))

from time import time

make(100,10000,0.01)
T=[]
T.append(time())
d = direct()
T.append(time())
e = einsum()
T.append(time())
print("results equal: ",np.allclose(d,e))
print("direct {:.6f} einsum {:.6f}".format(*np.diff(T)))
```

Sample run:

```
results equal:  True
direct 18.463711 einsum 1.947425
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help, however the output I am looking for is not necessarily an array. Especially, I may want to compute an even number of coefficients per row.

Comment: *uneven number of coefficients per rows

Comment: @AdrienVacher What makes you think this is not covered by this soln? It takes a ~1% random subset of all possible pairs, but instead you could use whatever subset you wish.

Comment: Yes sorry I should have tried it. Works perfectly, thanks !